# How can Xero api manage many organisations in one Xero app?

Tags: xero-api

Can I create multiple organizations using API. IF yes, then which Xero API should I use?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this time, you cannot create organisations via the Xero API. You can vote for this functionality via this user voice page: https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/9846840-myxero-api-read-create-update-organisations-as